# Scanner hasNextInt() return true if hasNextInt() has nothing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

After reading the hasNextInt() API, I'm still at a lost at this code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    input.next();
}
```

Why does the loop start even though input has nothing. Also, the hasNextInt() API mentions

> The scanner does not advance past any input.

What does that mean? And does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` is not a blocking call, it's just creating a new Scanner with `STDIN` as input. Thus execution proceeds to the while loop.

From the API documents at  [Oracle - Scanner (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Scanner waits (`input.hasNextInt()` at this moment is actually a blocking call) for the user to input something and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then on the `input.next()` call, it actually reads the input(consumes it) and advances the read position.

However, if you type something like `12 hello` as input in a terminal or console, this will cause the while loop to loop once and then exit. The reason for this is that `hasNextInt()` reads until the first whitespace and checks if the characters up to the whitespace are a valid `int`. In this case they are and `hasNextInt()` returns `true`. Then, on the second iteration of the loop, it encounters a `String`, thus `hasNextInt()` returns `false`, which causes the loop to end.

Comment: Doesn't that API only apply to hasNext() and not hasNextInt()? Also, do you have any good articles about blocking call? The book I'm reading has not mentioned anything about blocking calls.

Comment: Function with hasNext*(). I.e. hasNextLong(), hasNextByte(), hasNextShort() are blocking calls when you make that first call inside while loop. Now I have to tell you that if you type "12 hello" as input on terminal, this will cause while loop to loop once and then exist. Reason is that hasNext*() read until the first whitespace and check if its int, then on second loop it encounters a string, thus hasNextInt() returns false, that cause loop to break. I don't think there is a book dedicated for blocking calls, but most IO related calls are blocking calls unless you have some JAVA NIOs library